# Input validation with regex alphanumeric and allow only some special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a custom validation for an input box and tried with this. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\,/.-\s]*$/` 
 It will allow only the following special characters `, . / -` and blank space. I want to add one more special character and that is `\` 
 How can I achieve this.

Comment: Use: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9,/.\s\\-]+$/`

Comment: This is working fine for me. Thanks @anubhava